# vba How to custom format cells without changing value

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

Percentage etc. works fine, but a custom formatting doesn't allow me to SUM the nuber later.
.NumberFormat = "0.0%"

I have a series of dimensions and tried this:
.NumberFormat = "0.0mm" 
or
(formula) & "mm"

It looks correct, but I am not able to multiply this cell with other number cells as it reads it as text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The following works for me `.NumberFormat = "0.0 \m\m"`  It keeps the number and applies the mask, so `8.8` is seen as `8.8 mm` while keeping the number to use in other formulas.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Worked Perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells and run:

```
Sub MilliMeters()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.NumberFormat = "General"" mm"""
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Scott. This worked.
.NumberFormat = "0.0 \m\m"